# Facebook Admin Link Missing

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, facebook-social-plugins

I recently created a facebook application for integrating a domain's webpages with facebook.

But I can't figure out why the Admin Link will not show on the webpage whilst logged into fb as the admin.

Reading the developer documentation can be a little confusing since there seem to be various methods of implementing the code required on each webpage. It is difficult to determine which namespace matches with which way to load the SDK and with which markup method.

I am attempting to do this for HTML5.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- Whilst I have found many html namespace modifications for XFBML methods I did not see any requirements for html5 an    d the following method -->
<html>
<!-- The head og namespace is taken from the fb developers app > open graph > object types > get code link -->
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!-- The meta properties are also taken from the fb developers app > open graph > object types > get code link -->
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP ID NUMBER"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain.com/page.html"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.domain.com/og_thumb.jpg" />

<!-- The meta property here was not included with the above but is required according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ -->
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE NAME" />

</head>

<body>
<!-- The following is the code given when using the "like" code generator from this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and selecting the "HTML5" option -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP ID NUMBER";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.domain.com/page.html" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="0" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Whilst logged in as the admin user of the fb app I am able to visit the admin for the page by looking up the page name/id and append them to a url like so:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/TITLE-OF-PAGE/GRAPH-ID-NUMBER

I noticed this bug that seems related: 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/178579068908181/

I understand that when using fb:admins the admin must "like" a page before being able to see the Admin Link.

However I am assuming that when using fb:app_id that it should not be necessary to "like" the page.

What am I missing to enable the Admin Link for the webpage ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use both fb:app_id and fb:admins in the OG Markup. Don't forget to use the debug tool to scrape the page again so facebook knows that the details have changes. The admin link will only show if you have the fb:admins on the page.

You don't have to like the page, you could always wait for a user to like the page. Facebook will then create the associated page once it has enough likes and the admin link will appear correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the tardy response. I have tested with fb:admins too + run through debugger, but still no joy. It is a reproducible bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/312068448887757?browse=search_5031bc5d092e70230154166 which is given "low" priority